# Iteration Order in Ordered List

Tags: apex, order

I have an ordered list of a custom object which is the child of a different object. I want to get the earliest date of the child object per parent object. Here is a basic example:

```
List<objB__c> relChild = [SELECT id, objA__c, date 
                              FROM objB__c 
                              WHERE objA__c IN: objASet
                              ORDER BY date NULLS LAST];
```

So I should have a list of all children (objB) for any parent (objA) that I already have in a Set I had created earlier. Almost all the time there will only be one record in objASet, but I am trying to "bulkify" my code and allow it to handle multiple records just in case.

How can I pull the earliest date field from my list for each objA? Can I create a Map of id,Date and just iterate through the list? Or do I have to create a wrapper? [Or can I use the sort method in some way?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

Here is my idea for just doing a simple iteration:

```
Map<id,date> firstDate = new Map<id,date>();
    for(objB__c b: relChild){
        if(firstDate.containsKey(b.objA__c){} else {
            firstDate.put(b.objA__c, date); //would this get me the first date for each objA__c?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just negate the clause rather than using an empty `if` block...

Comment: ...by that you mean just add ! to the front?

Comment: Indeed. But you don't even need conditionals if you use aggregate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you just use aggregate queries here. You can then get just one row for each mapping you're trying to create. You could even do the nifty alias to `Id` trick so you can use the built in `Map` constructor.

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> minDates = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT Lookup__c Id, MIN(Date_Field__c) earliest FROM Child__c GROUP BY Lookup__c
]);
```

Then, if you have an `Id` for your parent, you can just do:

```
AggregateResult aggregate = minDates.get(parent.Id);
Date earliest = (aggregate == null) ? null : (Date)aggregate.get('earliest');
```

---

Just to note, your approach would work, but it is more clear and efficient to simply negate your clause.

```
if (!myMap.containsKey(...))
{
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I don't understand the syntax of the last line, though. What does the `(aggregate == null) ? null` do?

Comment: It's a `ternary operator`. It's the same as `Date earliest; if (aggregate != null) earliest = (Date)aggregate.get('earliest');`.